# What survival horror game is this image from?

Tags: game-identification

I found [this list of the 25 best horror games](http://www.gameranx.com/features/id/14616/article/best-survival-horror-games/) and I was intrigued about which game the title image is from?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not look like it is from any actual game.

The image looks like a mockup for a game some indie devs were working on.

http://www.deviantart.com/art/2D-survival-horror-game-mockup-subway-295184804

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Too bad they never made it into a real game.

Comment: Even though the image is not from an actual game, the art style is very similar to the one in Stasis.